# Segfault on fscanf

Tags: c

filenamelists is a struct with two file pointers. merge mergesorts these two fileptrs. I'm getting a segfault on the while(fscanf(filenamelist[0].file1, "%d", &chd) != EOF). I think its because I'm not implementing pthread correctly. Ive been trying to debug forever so any help would be appreciated. tempf is a file ptr to the mergesorted arrays. It is rewinded in the merge function itself.

```
 for(i=0; i<size; i++)
{
    if(argc==1)
    {
        char* tedious2 = (char*) malloc((strlen(argv[i+1]+7))*sizeof(char));
        strcpy(tedious2,argv[i+1]);
        filenamelist[i].file1 = fopen(strcat(tedious2,".sorted"),"r");
        filenamelist[i].file2 = NULL;
        filenamelist[i].alone = 1;
        free(tedious2);
        break;
    }
    else if(size-1 ==i && size%2 != 0)
    {
        char* tedious1 = (char*) malloc((strlen(argv[i+1]+7))*sizeof(char));
        strcpy(tedious1,argv[i+1]);
        filenamelist[i].file1 = fopen(strcat(tedious1,".sorted"),"r");
        filenamelist[i].file2 = NULL;
        filenamelist[i].alone = 1;
        free(tedious1);
    }
    else
    {
        char* tedious3 = (char*) malloc((strlen(argv[i+1]+7))*sizeof(char));
        strcpy(tedious3,argv[i+1]);
        char* tedious4 = (char*) malloc((strlen(argv[i+2]+7))*sizeof(char));
        strcpy(tedious4,argv[i+2]);
        filenamelist[i].file1 = fopen(strcat(tedious3,".sorted"),"r");
        filenamelist[i].file2 = fopen(strcat(tedious4,".sorted"),"r");
        filenamelist[i].alone = 0;
        free(tedious3);
        free(tedious4);
    }
}
```

//  pthread_t* threadid2;
//    threadid2 = (pthread_t*) malloc(sizeof(pthread_t)*(2*argc));

```
while(size>=0)
{

    i = 0;
    pthread_t* threadid2;
    threadid2 = (pthread_t*) malloc(sizeof(pthread_t)*size);
    for ( ; i<size;i++ )
    {
            pthread_create(&threadid2[i], NULL, merge, &filenamelist[i]);
    }
    i = 0;
    for ( ; i<size; i++)
    {
            pthread_join(threadid2[i], tempf);
        if (i%2 == 0)
        {
            filenamelist[i/2].file1 = tempf;
        }
        else
        {
            filenamelist[i/2].file2 = tempf;
        }

    }
        zit=0;
        truth = 0;
        while(zit<z)
        {
            if(inputFiles[zit] == tempf)
                truth = 1;
            zit++;
        }
        if(truth != 1)
        {  
            inputFiles[z] = tempf;
            z++;
        }
    if(size==1)
    size = 0;
    else if (size % 2 == 0) 
    size = size/2;
    else
    size = (size/2)+1;
    free(threadid2);

}

int chd = 0;
// if(0!=feof(tempf))
//   rewind(tempf);
//rewind(filenamelist[0]->file1);
int finish = 0;
//printf("file 1:%p",tempf);

while(fscanf(filenamelist[0].file1, "%d", &chd) != EOF) 
    finish++;
rewind(filenamelist[0].file1);

int* finarr = (int*) malloc(finish*sizeof(int));

int xx =0;

for(;fscanf(filenamelist[0].file1, "%d", &chd) != EOF; xx++)
    finarr[xx] = chd;
```

tempf is declared at start of func as FILE* tempf;

Comment: Was `filenamelist[0].file1` file handled opened earlier?

Comment: By filehandled do you mean accessed? Yes, i initialized it. I'll edit question with code.

Answer (score 1):

```
char* tedious2 = (char*) malloc((strlen(argv[i+1]+7))*sizeof(char));
```

Make that:

```
char *tedious2 = malloc( strlen(argv[i+1]) + strlen(".sorted") + 1 );
```

Comment: I don't think the argv[i+1] is right either, it is inside the `if (argc==1){}` block. So argv[xxx] might be a NULL pointer or worse.

Comment: No, I mean the + 1 for the NULL terminator at the end. And hopefully in his program `size` is `argc - 2`.

Comment: That was trivial (did you notice that the +7 is *inside* the {}, meaning that he actually allocates 7 bytes less (given that argv[xxx] is long enough?) But the argc-logic seems wrong, too. Anyway, it is hardly readable anyway.